# Enzyme - how to find multiple css selectors?

Tags: enzyme

I want to find these components using Enzyme's `find()` facility:

```
<PaneWrapper data-pane="...">
<PaneWorkspaceSearch data-pane="...">
```

I'm currently trying this pattern, but Enzyme does not recognise it:

```
wrapper.find('PaneWrapper[data-pane], PaneWorkspaceSearch[data-pane]');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I’d suggest using .findWhere and providing a function predicate rather than relying on string selectors here, since enzyme doesn’t yet support multiple complex selectors.